# Output come as string

Tags: javascript, prompt

I just want to add two numbers in javascript using prompt but the output comes as a string.

```
var num1 =prompt("enter a number");
var num2=prompt("enter a number");

var sum =num1+num2;

console.log(`the of ${num1}  and ${num2}  ${sum} `);
```

Comment: Prompt [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt). Convert it if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `prompt` is `string` so it is needed to convert string to number to do `sum` operation.

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("enter a number"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("enter a number"));

var sum =num1 + num2;

console.log(`the of ${num1}  and ${num2}  ${sum} `);
```

Comment: .W thanks bro, I was trying to find the solution the whole day now I get this so thanks bro once again.

Comment: Can you approve my answer if it works as expected? @TamimAhmed